# Cannot invoke initializer for type nsdictionary with an argument list of type(objects:String?for key [] string)

Tags: swift2, ios9

I want to add my data in dictionary in form of key value pair. But They give me error mentioned above. Here is my Code

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(objects: [getStringAt(selectStmt, column: 0), getStringAt(selectStmt, column: 1)], forKeys: ["username", "image"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that you're going to create an dictionary with optional `String` values.

Since all values in a dictionary must be non-optional you have to unwrap them.

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(objects: [getStringAt(selectStmt, column: 0)!, getStringAt(selectStmt, column: 1)!], forKeys: ["username", "image"])
```