# Cannot invoke initializer for type: Swift2

Tags: swift, swift2

I have migrated swift project from Xcode6.4 to Xcode7 but facing this error continuously and I could not find any solution for this problem.

```
let nviewsDictionary : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionaryLiteral: dptButton1 , "dptButton1" , txtNotes , "txtNotes")
```

> Error: Cannot invoke initializer for NSDictionary with an argument list of type..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot invoke initializer for type nsdictionary with an argument list of type(objects:String?for key \[\] string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338463/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-nsdictionary-with-an-argument-list-of-typeob)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was your original code but in Swift you probably don't want to use `NSDictionary` at all.

```
let nviewsDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["dptButton1": dptButton1, "txtNotes": txtNotes]
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sulthan noted, a regular Swift dictionary may be what you want, but if you need to use an `NSDictionary` for some reason you can create one like this:

```
let nviewsDictionary = NSDictionary(objects: [dptButton1, txtNotes], forKeys: [NSString(string: "dptButton1"), NSString(string: "txtNotes")])
```

Per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/initWithObjects:forKeys:) for `NSDictionary`, it does not look like the initializer that you were using is available.